# multiple Excel comments and validation.add weird behavior

Tags: vba, excel

I have quite complex Excel VBA project with sheets containing multiple comments and validations and came over some wierd issue several days ago.
It happened that after adding some additional comments to the sheet validation.add stopped working properly showing comment shape for some random cell right after validation.add execution within the cell under validation.
After investigation and some tests I was able to replicate the issue on an empty worksheet with the following code:

```
Sub CommentsBug()
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim rngItem As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C25000")
For Each rngItem In rng
    rngItem.Cells(1, 1).Value = i
    If rng.Comment Is Nothing Then rngItem.AddComment
    rngItem.Comment.Text "Comment # " & i
    i = i + 1
Next

ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Activate
ActiveCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3,4,5"

End Sub
```

After code execution I have comment box for a random cell appearing right within the validation cell (cannot put screenshot due to lack of rep).In case I change the last processed cell to C20000 the issue does not appear.
The system is Excel 2013 32-bit Office, Win 7 64.
I will be greatful for any advice and walkaround.

**UPDATE AND QUICK FIX:**

With the help of BruceWayne it was finally possible to get a quick fix (see below as approved answer). Somehow changing For Each statement to For and addressing separate cell ranges worked. 
It really seems to be a bug, see important comments of John Coleman and BruceWayne on its specifics below. Hopefully someone from Microsoft will come across it, I have also posted issue at answers.microsoft.com.
As soon as I already had a worksheet full of data, the following comments update code worked for me in order to get rid of appearing comment box (takes amazingly outstanding amount of time for large sheets - many hours, put the number of your rows/columns instead of 3000/500 in the cycle, remove protect/unprotect statements in case you do not have cell protection):

```
Public Sub RestoreComments()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim rng As Range
Dim commentString As String

Application.ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To 3000
    For j = 1 To 500
        Set rng = Cells(i, j)
          If Not rng.comment Is Nothing Then
            commentString = rng.comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text
            'commentString = GetStringFromExcelComment(rng.comment)
            'see Update #2
            rng.comment.Delete
            rng.AddComment
            rng.comment.Text commentString
            rng.comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
          End If
    Next j
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
Application.ActiveSheet.Protect userinterfaceonly:=True

End Sub
```

**UPDATE #2**

When performing restoring comments I also came across another issue of trancation of comment string exceeding 255 characters when using comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text. In case you have long comments use the following code to return comment string:

```
'Addresses an Excel bug that returns only first 255 characters
'when performing comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters.Text
Public Function GetStringFromExcelComment(comm As comment) As String
Dim ifContinueReading As Boolean
Dim finalStr As String, tempStr As String
Dim i As Long, commStrLimit As Long

ifContinueReading = True
commStrLimit = 255
i = 1
finalStr = ""

Do While ifContinueReading
    'Error handling addresses situation
    'when comment length is exactly the limit (255)
    On Error GoTo EndRoutine
    tempStr = comm.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(i, commStrLimit).Text
    finalStr = finalStr + tempStr
    If Len(tempStr) < commStrLimit Then
        ifContinueReading = False
    Else
        i = i + commStrLimit
    End If
Loop

EndRoutine: GetStringFromExcelComment = finalStr

End Function
```

The solution was found in the following thread (slightly changed to address the string exactly matching the limit):
[Excel Comment truncated during reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531164/excel-comment-truncated-during-reading)

Comment: Just a comment, I'm also trying to figure out what's going on too - it seems to always be comment 9464.  It's correctly creating the comment, but for some reason when you hover over the Validation in E1, the comment pops up alllll the way at the top. Hm.. I changed the range to go to `C26000` and the comment that shows up is now comment 12464.

Comment: when I traced comment box appeared within the cell right after validation.add call....

Comment: Another note: I made the Validation part of your code a separate Sub.  When I just ran the main part, I could hover over "E1" without the comment popping up. When I then run `ws.Range("e1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3,4,5"` as a separate sub, then hover E1, the  comment pops up. Hmmmmmm.

Comment: With Excel 2010 on my machine I needed to turn-off screenupdating during the main loop since otherwise it would hang. I see the bug -- but if I then delete columns A:E and rerun the sub the bug doesn't reappear.

Comment: @JohnColeman - so you mean you can run the macro once, then delete A:E, and run again and you don't get the bug? Without changing anything at all in the code? Weird...

Comment: @BruceWayne - yes, that is what happens. But -- it takes about 20 seconds to delete those columns.

Comment: @user4047625 kudos on doing such a nice job of describing a reproducible bug. Maybe you can file a bug report with Microsoft.

Comment: I also put a question to Microsoft Community, hopefully they either explain or finally resolve the issue. Meanwhile, I am trying to apply and check proposed quick fix. After the bug in my main sheet I also noticed considerable performance penalty when populating validations and also some further buggy behavor after changing selection (for instance, list selection arrows do not disappear when changing selection).

Comment: @user4047625 - thanks for your staying with it and working through it! If you ever learn anything from the Microsoft Community, would you mind posting an update in your OP so we can learn too?  Thanks, and again great job on the reproducible error and nice find!

Comment: @BruceWayne Another issue found on comment string trancation (see update).

Comment: @user4047625 - nice finds, thanks for updating us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, after tweaking the code, I found that if you change the For() loop, you can stop the comment from appearing.  Try this:

```
Sub CommentsBug()
Dim rng           As Range
Dim i             As Long
Dim rngItem       As Range
Dim ws            As Worksheet
Dim k As Integer, x As Integer

Set ws = ActiveSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C25000")

For k = 1 To 25000
    If i > 25000 Then Exit For

    For x = 1 To 3
        Set rngItem = Cells(k, x)
        Cells(k, x).Value = i
        If rng.Comment Is Nothing Then rngItem.AddComment
        rngItem.Comment.Text "Comment # " & i
        rngItem.Comment.Visible = False
        rngItem.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

        i = i + 1
    Next x
Next k

ws.Range("E1").Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3,4,5"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayCommentIndicator = xlCommentIndicatorOnly
End Sub
```

Note: This might take a little bit longer to run, but it doesn't give the same random comment popping up as yours does. Also, as for why this works and the other For() loop won't, I have no idea.  I suspect it's something to do with the way Excel uses Validation, instead of it being something with the code (but that's pure speculation, perhaps someone else knows what is going on).

Comment: Bruce, many thanks! Would never think of changing cycle statement.... I will try applying this to my main code and revert.

Comment: That seems to fix the bug, but took around a minute to run on my machine. My hunch is that the 75,000 comments exceed the maximum number of comments in some earlier version of Excel and that in some unknown way this triggers the bug. It would be interesting to see if the bug pops up at around 32768 comments.

Comment: @JohnColeman - yeah, it takes a minute for me too.  I tried leaving it `Dim i` to set as `Variant`, but I still get the buggy comment box.  It's probably worth noting that it's the SAME comment each time for the bug.  And if you increase the range size, it'll occur on a new comment, but that comment number remains constant if you re-run the macro.

Comment: @JohnColeman - Ok, I set `i` to `integer`, and of course get Overflow error when it gets to 32768.  HOWEVER, if I then add the validation, the issue doesn't show up!  Hmmm - I guess it has something to do with the number of comments and this specific For() loop?

Comment: I would expect bug at 65536 records, but actually on my main sheet it appeared after inserting a bunch of comments at 61125 (if we trust Activesheet.comments.count), i.e. the bound was lower than that.... probably depends also on comment text size, etc....

Comment: @user4047625 - does the code work for you, or does it still provide some funky error?

Comment: Dear Bruce, my initial portion of code is a bit more complex, so it takes time to integrate and check. I will mark the question as answered as soon as I finish.

Comment: I guess I was thinking of things like the limit of 32767 characters in a cell, though 65536 is also a plausible threshold. It can't be a coincidence that 75000 mod 65536 = 9464 -- the number that labeled the phantom comment. Sounds like an `unsigned int` variable somewhere in Excel's code base wasn't updated to a `long` and is wrapping around when incremented. As to why the error should surface there -- who knows. Maybe some sort of writing past the end of an array.

Comment: @BruceWayne and JohnColeman. Thank you, guys. For this moment I have done with the issue. FYI - it took the whole night for Excel to delete and add comments for approx. 60 000 cells on my base sheet... really frustrating...

Comment: @user4047625 Do you *really* need 60,000 comments? Why not just write a selection change procedure that automatically generates and displays a comment when the cell is clicked on? My guess is that only a very small fraction of those comments will ever be used -- why not generate them on the fly?

Comment: @JohnColeman Dear John, my comments contain information that is used while interacting with db... at this stage it is quite hard to change the logic. if I would knew bug/performance issue I would probably reconsider approach while planning...

Comment: @BruceWayne Just faced the problem again, started to experiment and understood why your solution works. It just does not go beoynd 25 000 records (on i>25000 exits cycle) ;)

Comment: @user4047625 - What if you just declare `i` as `Variant`? (`Dim i`).  I am afraid though we're wading into an issue with Excel itself, and not just how we declare a variable.  (Ooh, another idea maybe...Create some other variable (say, `k`).  When i = 25000, set k = 25001 and see if you can use K from that point on ...does that make sense? I think it'll still give you some gruff, but it's worth a shot perhaps.

Comment: @BruceWayne i experimented quite a lot with the code. the bug seems to be unbeatable for the moment. the only solution I found is to identify faulty cell cycling through all comments and using 'If ActiveSheet.Comments(i).Shape.Top = ActiveCell.Top'.... and then restoring comment for the cell (delete/add). In this case the bug disappears for the end of the session with Excel. Still it takes a lot  time for large worksheet... Anyway, thank you for you efforts and advise. In case I find another solution, I will let you know.

Comment: @user4047625 - thank *you* for your staying with it, and clarity in reproducing this error.  Good thinking with the `If` statement.. Thanks for keeping us updated!

Answer (score 1):

This kludge seems to work (although there is no guarantee that the underlying bug won't bubble to the surface somewhere else)

```
Sub CommentsBug()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rngItem As Range
    Dim kludgeIndex As Long
    Dim kludgeRange As Range
    Dim temp As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C25000")
    kludgeIndex = rng.Cells.Count Mod 65536
    For Each rngItem In rng
        rngItem.Cells(1, 1).Value = i
        If i = kludgeIndex Then Set kludgeRange = rngItem
        If rngItem.Comment Is Nothing Then rngItem.AddComment "Comment # " & i
        i = i + 1
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Activate
    ActiveCell.Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2,3,4,5"

    If Not kludgeRange Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print kludgeRange.Address 'in case you are curious
        temp = kludgeRange.Comment.Text
        kludgeRange.Comment.Delete
        kludgeRange.AddComment temp
    End If
End Sub
```

When run like above, kludgeRange is cell $C$3155 -- which displays 9464. If the 25000 is changed to 26000, kludgeRange becomes cell $C$4155, which displays 12464. This is a truly weird kludge where to exorcise the ghost from cell E1 you have to go thousands of cells away.

Comment: Dear John, thank you for this! I was also thinking on identifying kludge range and re-writing its comment right after validation.add..

Comment: Never heard of "kludge" before, that'll be a handy word for sure!

Comment: @BruceWayne: from Wikipedia: "In modern computing terminology, a kludge (or often a "hack") is a solution to a problem, doing a task, or fixing a system that is inefficient, inelegant or even unfathomable, but which nevertheless (more or less) works". This particular one is of the unfathomable variety.

Comment: @JohnColeman - okay that describes perfectly half of my Macros when I was learning VB, Python, C...etc. hahaha.  Great word!